# Update corresponding label depending on which combobox fired the event

Tags: delphi, combobox, event-handling

I have a program with `n` `ComboBoxes` and `n` `Labels` and I want to update the corresponding `Label` depending on the selection from the adjacent `ComboBox` i.e `ComboBox2` would update `Label2`.

[image]

I am using the same event handler for every `ComboBox` and currently checking if `Combobox1` or `Combobox2` has fired the event handler. Is there a way to use the `ItemIndex` of the `ComboBox` passed to the procedure, such as `Sender.ItemIndex`? This is not currently an option and gives the error `'TObject' does not contain a member named 'ItemIndex'`.

```
procedure TForm2.ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender = ComboBox1 then
    Label1.Caption := ComboBox1.Items.Strings[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]
  else
    Label2.Caption := ComboBox2.Items.Strings[ComboBox2.ItemIndex];
end;
```

This code has the desired behavior but is obviously not scale-able.

Comment: You can cast the sender as TCombobox: (Sender as TCombobox).ItemIndex

Comment: As an aside, if the user must choose one of the items in the CB list, and may not enter a custom text, *please* change the CBs' styles to `csDropDownList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1

This is the most robust one.

Let your form have private members

```
private
  FControlPairs: TArray<TPair<TComboBox, TLabel>>;
  procedure InitControlPairs;
```

and call `InitControlPairs` when the form is created (either in its constructor, or in its `OnCreate` handler):

```
procedure TForm1.InitControlPairs;
begin
  FControlPairs :=
    [
      TPair<TComboBox, TLabel>.Create(ComboBox1, Label1),
      TPair<TComboBox, TLabel>.Create(ComboBox2, Label2),
      TPair<TComboBox, TLabel>.Create(ComboBox3, Label3)
    ]
end;
```

You need to add the controls to this array manually. That's the downside of this approach. But you only need to do this once, right here. Then everything else can be done automagically.

Now, this is where it gets really nice: Let all your comboboxes share this `OnChange` handler:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBoxChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(FControlPairs) do
    if FControlPairs[i].Key = Sender then
      FControlPairs[i].Value.Caption := FControlPairs[i].Key.Text;
end;
```

## Option 2

Forget about any private fields. Now instead make sure that each pair has a unique `Tag`. So the first combo box and label both have `Tag = 1`, the second pair has `Tag = 2`, and so on. Then you can do simply

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBoxChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  TargetTag: Integer;
  CB: TComboBox;
  i: Integer;
begin

  if Sender is TComboBox then
  begin

    CB := TComboBox(Sender);
    TargetTag := CB.Tag;

    for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
      if (Controls[i].Tag = TargetTag) and (Controls[i] is TLabel) then
      begin
        TLabel(Controls[i]).Caption := CB.Text;
        Break;
      end;

  end;

end;
```

as the shared combo-box event handler. The downside here is that you must be sure that you control the Tag properties of all your controls on the form (at least with the same parent as your labels). Also, they must all have the same parent control.

Comment: Of course, in the first `ComboBoxChanged`, you might also choose to `Break` after the first match, if you know you never have two labels connected to the same CB.

Comment: Also consider using `FindComponent('Label' + IntToStr(TargetTag))` to find the label.

Comment: @Olivier: I am not a huge fan of using string-based methods to find controls, but sure, in practice that works absolutely fine too! And there are even more options: the OP could create a frame or a custom control (deriving from `TCustomControl`).

Answer (score 5):

Every component has a `Tag` property inherited from `TComponent`, where the `Tag` is a pointer-sized integer. As such, you can store each `TLabel` pointer directly in the corresponding `TComboBox.Tag`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Tag := NativeInt(Label1);
  ComboBox2.Tag := NativeInt(Label2);
end;
```

This way, `ComboBoxChange()` can then directly access the `TLabel` of the changed `TComboBox`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  CB: TComboBox;
begin
  CB := TComboBox(Sender);
  if CB.Tag <> 0 then
    TLabel(CB.Tag).Caption := CB.Items.Strings[CB.ItemIndex];
end;
```

Comment: No loop, No variables and Optimized, as usual beautifully done.